# What are the signs of wchar_t on Apple targets?

Tags: ios, c, macos, darwin

AFAICT `wchar_t` is always 32-bit wide on Apple targets.

What is the sign of `wchar_t` on:

- x86 Apple Darwin (32-bit MacOSX)
- x86_64 Apple Darwin (64-bit MacOSX)
- ARM iOS (32-bit)
- AArch64 iOS (64-bit)

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO/IEC 9899:2017 §7.20.3/4:

> If `wchar_t` (see 7.19) is defined as a signed integer type, the value of `WCHAR_MIN` shall be no greater than −127 and the value of `WCHAR_MAX` shall be no less than 127; otherwise, `wchar_t` is defined as an unsigned integer type, and the value of `WCHAR_MIN` shall be 0 and the value of `WCHAR_MAX` shall be no less than 255.

So looking at `WCHAR_MIN` will tell you.

---

[iOS ABI Function Call Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARM64FunctionCallingConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013702-SW1):

> In iOS, as with other Darwin platforms, both `char` and `wchar_t` are signed types.

Comment: "So looking at WCHAR_MIN will tell you." I know, the question is: what's the sign of the value that this returns on these systems?

Comment: @gnzlbg That's up to the compiler, not the architecture.

Comment: I thought the ABI of these architectures required a specific type. As in, independently what compiler you use, if you wanted to call a kernel ABI handling this you'd have to stick to whatever ABI the kernel expected. 

How many compiles target these architectures? I thought it was just clang. How do other compilers differ from clang here? AFAICT there is only one C and C++ standard library available for these. So if you wanted to use those, you'd have to do what they expect.

Comment: @gnzlbg gcc with glibc also runs on OS X. OS X is FreeBSD after all.

Comment: Sure, but independently of the compiler, the OSX kernel and standard library APIs will expect a particular `wchar_t` type. What's its sign? I'd expect that for this target clang and gcc would need to agree.

Comment: Thank you. That's slightly different from FreeBSD, where AFAIK `char` and `wchar_t` are unsigned on arm32 and arm64 targets, but signed on 32 and 64-bit x86.